# Grails Deploy XAMPP Tomcat

Tags: grails, xampp, tomcat7

I was about to test my grails application using the XAMPP Tomcat server for checking.
I followed the instruction set [here](http://ist.mns.kyutech.ac.jp/miura/inlinelink/warinstall.html) regarding how to deploy the `.war` file into the web-app folder of the Tomcat.

The project did deploy within the workspace of Tomcat but when I tried to start the project and restarted Tomcat I get this error message:

> FAIL - Application at context path /[Project Name] could not be started

I also tried using the command `grails> tomcat deploy`, I get this error message on the console:

> Error Error executing script Tomcat: : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2F[Project Name] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

My question is what is the proper way of deploying Grails application with the following Tomcat specifications:

- Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
- JVM Version: 1.6.0_31-b05

Comment: "The project did deploy within the workspace of Tomcat" - I don't understand this sentence. Are you trying to deploy inside Eclipse (or some other IDE)?

Answer (score 2):

To [create the war file](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html):

```
grails prod war
```

Check the `target` folder for a war with your app name and version.

Then move the file to `webapps` folder of Tomcat. If Tomcat is [configured to auto deploy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup), you will see the content of your war file extracted inside webapps.

Finally just open localhost:8080/yourapp/

Comment: @Dr.Java: you should check the tomcat server log then. It maybe an error in the code.